# DXGrid load data asynchronously + editable

Tags: asynchronous, grid, devexpress, devforce

I am trying to implement the DevExpress Grid in an asynchronous way, which means that I would like it to load a set amount of data and be able to edit the loaded data.
DevExpress is providing a [EntityInstantFeedbackSource](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressDataLinqEntityInstantFeedbackSourcetopic) class which can be used to load data asynchronously. The problem is that this class does not provide the ability to edit the data and it also seems to produce problems when used with DevForce as entity provider ([link to the Problem](http://www.ideablade.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=3309&title=devexpress-entityinstantfeedbacksource-and-devforce))

There seems to be an interface (IAsyncListServer) on DevExpress side, but it looks like if they don't recommend to implement it just yet as it may change in the future and it also seems quite complex for what I try to achieve and I already tried to implement the interface without any success. I did the following:
Created a class which implemented every method of IAsyncListServer and used it as source for the grid. The problem is that none of the methods seem to get called from the grid.

Maybe someone has an idea for a workaround or something to achieve this kind of functionality with the DXGrid.

If this is not possible are there any other Grid options with a better support for such a requirement? I already tried Xceed which seems to be nice but my problem with them is that they do not provide a full suite of controlls.

Comment: You can allow editing data in stand-alone forms, that are not bound to the asynchronous datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx) together with the [WCFInstantFeedbackSource](http://documentation.devexpress.dev/#WPF/clsDevExpressDataWcfLinqWcfInstantFeedbackSourcetopic). This is a good tandem for implementing asunchronous views in multi-tier application.

Though, WCFInstantFeedbackSource is also read only.